# Invalid hook call of useRef()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to assing refs dinamically, but I get the error "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component" when useRef. Here:

```js
const [subsistemaPlanetario, setSubsistemaPlanetario] = useState([]);
const planetRefs = useRef({});

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchSubsistemaPlanetario() {
    try {
      const fetchedSubsistemaPlanetario = await getSubsistemaPlanetario();
      setSubsistemaPlanetario(fetchedSubsistemaPlanetario);

      fetchedSubsistemaPlanetario.forEach((planeta) => {
        const camelCaseSlug = planeta.padre.slug.replace(/-([a-z])/g, (_, letter) => letter.toUpperCase());
        planetRefs.current[camelCaseSlug] = useRef(); // <------THIS LINE DROP AN ERROR
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  fetchSubsistemaPlanetario();
}, []);
```

ENTIRE COMPONENT:

```js
import {useFrame} from '@react-three/fiber';
import React, {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Planet} from './Planet.jsx';
import {Satellite} from './Satellite.jsx';
import {Orbiter} from './utils/Orbiter.js';
import {calculateOrbitalPeriod} from './utils/calculateOrbitalPeriod.js';

import {getSubsistemaPlanetario} from './utils/getSubsistemaPlanetario.js';

export const SubsistemaPlanetario = function SubsistemaPlanetario(props) {
  let running = true;
  let stopRunning = () => (running = false);
  let startRunning = () => (running = true);

  const [subsistemaPlanetario, setSubsistemaPlanetario] = useState([]);
  const planetRefs = useRef({});

  useEffect(() => {
    // Obtener el subsistema planetario cuando el componente se monta
    async function fetchSubsistemaPlanetario() {
      try {
        const fetchedSubsistemaPlanetario = await getSubsistemaPlanetario();
        
        setSubsistemaPlanetario(fetchedSubsistemaPlanetario);

        fetchedSubsistemaPlanetario.forEach((planeta) => {
          const camelCaseSlug = planeta.padre.slug.replace(/-([a-z])/g, (_, letter) => letter.toUpperCase());

          planetRefs.current[camelCaseSlug] = useRef();
          console.log(planetRefs);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    fetchSubsistemaPlanetario();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {subsistemaPlanetario.map((planetaPadre, index) => (
        <Planet
          key={index}
          scale={0.5}
          ref={planetRefs.current[index]}
          stopRunning={stopRunning}
          startRunning={startRunning}
          textureType="haumea"
          linkTo="areas"
          linkToLabel="Areas"
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

PLANET COMPONENT

```
import {forwardRef, useRef, useEffect, useContext, useState} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {useTexture} from '@react-three/drei';
import {useFrame} from '@react-three/fiber';
import barba from '@barba/core';
import {solapaContentAbrir, solapaContentCerrar} from './utils/Solapa.js';
import {planets} from './utils/arrayTexturas.js';

// Define un objeto que mapea los tipos de textura a las rutas de los archivos de textura.
const textureMap = {};

for (const planet of planets) {
  textureMap[planet] = `./app/themes/sage/resources/scripts/cosmos/components/textures/${planet}-512.jpg`;
}

export const Planet = forwardRef(function Planet(props, ref) {
  // Obtén la ruta de la textura según el tipo especificado en props.textureType.
  const texturePath = textureMap[props.textureType] || textureMap.sand;
  const texture = useTexture(texturePath);

  let rotationX = Math.random();
  let rotationY = Math.random();

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    ref.current.rotation.x += rotationX * delta;
    ref.current.rotation.y += rotationY * delta;
  });

  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      castShadow
      receiveShadow
      onPointerEnter={(event) => {
        props.stopRunning();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        solapaContentAbrir('Sección', props.linkToLabel);
        event.stopPropagation();
      }}
      onPointerLeave={(event) => {
        props.startRunning();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        solapaContentCerrar();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }}
      onClick={(event) => {
        barba.go(props.linkTo);
      }}
    >
      <sphereGeometry />
      <meshStandardMaterial map={texture} />
    </mesh>
  );
});

Planet.propTypes = {
  stopRunning: PropTypes.func,
  startRunning: PropTypes.func,
  textureType: PropTypes.oneOf(['haumea', 'mars', 'neptune', 'venus', 'mercury', 'jupiter', 'saturn']),
  userData: PropTypes.object,
  radius: PropTypes.number,
  linkTo: PropTypes.string,
  linkToLabel: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve on that line?

Comment: Please share code of whole file ie from first line so that we can see exactly where is it being used.

Comment: Trying to create a ref in the planetRefs object for each "planet". (Not sure if it is correct)

Comment: Done, I've edited the question.

Comment: You are trying to break the rules. See [this](https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).
If you are trying to remember data, use `useMemo` instead

Comment: this comes up often, but i can't find the dupes. use a ref to an array, object, or Map, etc.

Comment: What are you even trying? Why do you need this ref outside of Planet?
Given your code, I don't see a reason why you would need to store the ref outside of the Planet itself. The only place you seem to use it, is within Planet itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned here, you simply cant use hooks in any form of control flow.
So no `if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, `forEach`, `callback`, ...

You can use `ref={}` with a callback, like this:

```js
<Planet
          key={index}
          ref={(ref) => {planetRefs[index] = ref}}
```

but apart from that, there's no way to keep the refs like you have them.

Edit:
I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but there's no need to have a ref to the Planet outside of Planet itself.
(Honestly, there might not even be a need for a ref at all)
You could simply update the rotation within Planet and be done with it.

```js
export const Planet = function Planet(props, ref) {
  // ...

  const ref = useRef();
  let rotationX = Math.random();
  let rotationY = Math.random();

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    ref.current.rotation.x += rotationX * delta;
    ref.current.rotation.y += rotationY * delta;
  });

  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      // ...
    >
      // ...
  );
};

// ...
```

Alternatively, if the refs are really required outside, and in my opinion it rarely is, create an array/object and pass it to the Planet component.

```js
const planets = useRef({});

// ...

planets.forEach((planet) => {
  return <Planet key={planet.slug} planets={planets.current} ... />
});


function Planet(props) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Add it to the list of planets when component is rendered
    props.planets[props.slug] = ref;
  }, () => {
    // Remove when no longer needed
    props.planets[props.slug] = undefined;
  });

  // ...
}
```

You would be able to access it using

```js
  planets.current[slug].current
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to have the reference available within the planet component. If inside Planet I do `console.log(ref);` It returns the callback function instead of the reference.

Comment: @aitor I've added a solution implementing that issue. But I really think you should think about it, if you really need the ref outside of Planet. Usually it's an indicator of bad separation (in my experience)

Comment: Totally right. Thank you very much. The right approach is to keep position updates inside component.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve here.

```
ref={planetRefs.current[index]}
```

will do nothing since `planetRefs.current` is an *empty object* and will remain as an *empty object* since you are not assigning any value to it.

```
planetRefs.current[camelCaseSlug] = useRef();
```

will also do nothing since you can't use *react hooks* inside a function that is not a *react component*.

---

> By the way - why you are assigning the ref value as `camelCaseSlug` but in the render you are trying to access it by `index`?

---

##### Possible solution

I think you should be using a *callback* ref instead, to get the access to the rendered elements:

```
ref={(ref) => {
   planetRefs.current[index] = ref;
}}
```

**Note**: Remember to wrap your `Planet` component with `forwardRef`.

##### Edit:

You can remove the `planetRefs.current[camelCaseSlug] = useRef();` part completely. If you prefer to keep the `refs` in the `planetRefs` as slugs, just modify the *callback ref* a bit:

```
ref={(ref) => {
   const camelCaseSlug = planetaPadre.padre.slug
      .replace(/-([a-z])/g, (_, letter) => letter.toUpperCase());

   planetRefs.current[camelCaseSlug] = ref;
}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer . I'm afraid this is too much for my level. I don't understand the callback ref. When I implement it, the ref is no accesible in the Planet component. I appreciate your efforts, really.

Comment: @aitor To access the ref, you need to use the `forwardRef` function on your `Planet` component. Please check: https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef

Comment: Yes, I have it: `export const Planet = forwardRef(function Planet(props, ref) {}`

Comment: @aitor Remember to pass the `ref` value to the component you like. For example `<div ref={ref}>{...}</div>`. Ref has to be assigned to some element.

Comment: @aitor Would be best if you just shown me your `Planet` component :)

Comment: writing a a comment! one minute :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255474/discussion-between-aitor-and-kind-user).

Comment: @aitor Please just edit your question and paste the `Planet` component :)

Comment: @aitor Thank you for your edit. Im not sure why you want to pass the refs dynamically. You want to have access to the `Planet` component from parent? If not, you should move the `useRef` usage to the `Planet` component, just as it is shown on: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/getting-started/introduction (take a look here, the `useRef` is used in the `Box` component, like your `Planet`).

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment. Yes you're right. I have already seen what my mistake was. I'm trying to update the positions from the parent component, when it's not necessary. I can do the calculations in the Planet component. This will also make all the code cleaner. I thank you very much for all the help I have received. It has been very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a hook conditionally for your component

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.